# how to find the gradient using differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I did not understand what do they want from the question, can you help me please?

> Find the gradient at the point with $x$-coordinate $3$ on each of the
>   following curves:  $y = 2x^2 − 8x + 3$

Thank you.

Comment: **HINT**: The gradient is defined as the slope of the curve which in turn can be calculated by finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$. You then need to work out the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at the point $x=3$

Answer (score 1):

$y'=4x-8$
or, $y'(3)=4(3)-8$
or, $y'(3)=12-8$
or, $y'(3)=4$